# How to make ajax call inside javascript on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ubuntu

I am using `NodeJS` and a Javascript file to make AJAX calls. I installed and imported jQuery as shown below:

```
  var http = require("http");
  $ = require("jquery");
    test();

  function test() {
  $.ajax({ ... )}; }
```

If I run this with `node hello.js`, it says:

> TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

I also tried `add $(document).ready` and `$function ()` before the AJAX call, but it couldn't find the document. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's ajax is basically a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which works in a browser and not in nodejs.

For nodejs you'll have to use it's [http](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html) api... If want something that looks like jQuery's ajax try [ajax-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-request)